# Office uri schema to open Visio in desktop

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, visio

[Office Uri Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes) to open Visio documents stored on Sharepoint in desktop app is not working. As per official documentation I tried following but didn't worked. Browser is not detecting **ms-visio** command.

- ms-visio:ofv|u|https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/XYZ/ABC/test.vsdx
- ms-visio:ofe|u|https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/XYZ/ABC/test.vsdx

Comment: Have you tried to repair Visio? The registration is in the (desktop) registry, so repair could help.

Comment: @Nikolay Yes I reinstalled Visio on my system and it started working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visio must be installed on your system. If it is already there then try to repair it or at last reinstall Visio. That worked for me.